# Use ANT to execute existing ApexTests

Tags: unit-test, ant, test-setup

I would like to periodically execute local tests in an org outside of a package deployment.

I have a deploy entry in my build.xml file that sets testLevel="RunLocalTests", and has an entry for deployRoot. I tried removing deployRoot from the target, but ANT says that either deployRoot or zipFile is required.

Is there a way to execute the tests without having a package to deploy? I would like to run tests sitting in the org, I'm not deploying any new tests or other objects.

Comment: Can you add some detail about what you've already tried and where you are stuck? You should at least be able to demonstrate that you have done some rudimentary research.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the new compileAndTest task to run tests without a package.xml.

Your build.xml can look like this:

```
<project name="salesforce" xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">
  <property environment="env" />
  <property file="build.properties" />
  <target name="compileAndTest">
    <sf:compileAndTest username="${username}" 
                       password="${password}" 
                       serverurl="${serverurl}">
      <sf:runTests namespace="Default" />
    </sf:compileAndTest>
  </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Where did you find compileAndTest?  I can't find it in the docs anywhere.

Comment: @NickCook It's in the source code. I tried to find documentation on this, honest, but all I came up with are people asking for the documentation. And, apparently, it's not really new, it looks like it's close to 9 years old, just not formally documented. The best I came up with is to read [compileAndTest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/sforce_api_calls_compileandtest.htm), which is what this task is based off of. Uses all the same parameters.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox.  I was looking for something like this but assumed it didn't exist.  I wanted an automated way to run all tests in a production org without having to do a deployment of code (jenkins triggered for a managed package org)

Comment: @NickCook FWIW, using `sf:deploy checkOnly="true" testLevel="RunLocalTests"` is also acceptable, but I wanted this "documented" since I couldn't seem to find a decent example anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an `ant` executed test run but one option for you to consider. You can run tests in an org using the `ApexTestQueueItem` and the apex scheduler to run tests in an automated manner on a given schedule.

SFDC Documentation: [Apex: Run Unit Test Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_unit_tests_running.htm)

Here's the example code from the documentation which queues up execution of all classes that end in the word "Test".

```
public class TestUtil {

    // Enqueue all classes ending in "Test". 
    public static ID enqueueTests() {
        ApexClass[] testClasses = 
           [SELECT Id FROM ApexClass 
            WHERE Name LIKE '%Test'];
        if (testClasses.size() > 0) {
            ApexTestQueueItem[] queueItems = new List<ApexTestQueueItem>();
            for (ApexClass cls : testClasses) {
                queueItems.add(new ApexTestQueueItem(ApexClassId=cls.Id));
            }

            insert queueItems;

            // Get the job ID of the first queue item returned.
            ApexTestQueueItem item = 
               [SELECT ParentJobId FROM ApexTestQueueItem 
                WHERE Id=:queueItems[0].Id LIMIT 1];
            return item.parentjobid;
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Get the status and pass rate for each class
    // whose tests were run by the job.
    // that correspond to the specified job ID.
    public static void checkClassStatus(ID jobId) {
        ApexTestQueueItem[] items = 
           [SELECT ApexClass.Name, Status, ExtendedStatus 
            FROM ApexTestQueueItem 
            WHERE ParentJobId=:jobId];
        for (ApexTestQueueItem item : items) {
            String extStatus = item.extendedstatus == null ? '' : item.extendedStatus;
            System.debug(item.ApexClass.Name + ': ' + item.Status + extStatus);
        }
    }

    // Get the result for each test method that was executed.
    public static void checkMethodStatus(ID jobId) {
        ApexTestResult[] results = 
           [SELECT Outcome, ApexClass.Name, MethodName, Message, StackTrace 
            FROM ApexTestResult 
            WHERE AsyncApexJobId=:jobId];
        for (ApexTestResult atr : results) {
            System.debug(atr.ApexClass.Name + '.' + atr.MethodName + ': ' + atr.Outcome);
            if (atr.message != null) {
                System.debug(atr.Message + '\n at ' + atr.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark... I started off this way, then found you can just use `[FIND '@isTest' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ApexClass(Id)]` instead; this is more reliable than depending on all developers naming their classes "correctly."

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I have put together is to create an "empty" package. I have a folder with a package.xml file that contains no objects.

Comment: I'm going to put together a compileAndTest answer for you.